# How to get id for every data point in highchart

Tags: highcharts

Actually i am using the Highstock library and I am generating a graph with line chart (Data Grouping) with using PHP and MySQL. I am using a JSON format to plot the chart.

I have around 50,000 records to plot chart and I need to show **id** in popup when I click on data point.

I use my JSON string like this

```
[
[1345575960000,303.38,1],
[1345575960000,303.32,2],
[1345575960000,303.25,3],
[1345575960000,303.17,4],
[1345575960000,303.09,5],
[1345575960000,303.01,6]
]
```

in javascript i am using

```
$.getJSON('data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name +'.json&callback=?', function(data) {

var jsonData = [],
dataLength = data.length;

for (j = 0; j < dataLength; j++) {
    jsonData.push([
        data[j][0], // x value
        data[j][1], // y value
        data[j][2] // id
    ]);
}

seriesOptions[i] = {
    name: name,
    data: jsonData,
    events:
        {
            click: function(event)
            {
                chart.showLoading('Loading data...');
                // HOW TO GET HERE THE ID (This is third value in JSON array)
                chart.hideLoading();
            }
        }
    };
seriesCounter++;
if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
      createChart();
}

});
```

Can anyone help me show the ID in Chart.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at example which contains 60000 points and ids are displayed correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rpkqa/

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = 0; i <= 60000; i++) {
                data.push({
                    id: 'iddd' + i,
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                });
            }
            return data;
        })()
    }]
```

tooltip:

```
 tooltip:{
        formatter:function(){
            console.log(this);

            return 'point: '+this.y + ' ID: '+this.points[0].point.id;
        }
    },
```

Comment: I agree the given example shows the ID but when I Click on Zoom ALL or 5M then it also appears ID is undefined.

Comment: Because when you load this data, then datagrouping works, so you need to disable it, but you should be aware of in this amount of points you need to set huge widht of div.

Comment: how can i disable datagrouping

Comment: Is it possible to perform click event in a particular Data Grouping? So that when we zoom the chart then perform the click event otherwise we can not perform click event.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your points differently. Try this:

```
[
    {x:1345575960000,y:303.38,id:1},
    {x:1345575960000,y:303.32,id:2}
]
```

You should then be able refer to this.id in the evnt handler.

Comment: Dear SteveP, I changed my JSON string according to you but now my chart is not appear

Comment: Is there any limit of JSON array to pass this way [
    {x:1345575960000,y:303.38,id:1},
    {x:1345575960000,y:303.32,id:2}
]

Comment: Yeap, default limit is to 1000, see [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold). However dataGrouping will create new points, so all 'id' properties will be removed.

Comment: I agree with the limit of 1000 and i increase turboThreshold with 50,000. Now it plots my chart and I am using JSON in this format [
    {x:1345575960000,y:303.38,id:1},
    {x:1345575960000,y:303.32,id:2}
]. But when i pass 623 records then i can get the ID with this.id but when I increase a single number of record (624 and above) then it plots my chart but this.id return undefined.